# [dcc32 Warning] SerAndDeser.pas(298): W1036 Variable 'tForm' might not have been initialized

Tags: переменные, delphi, delphi-7, инициализация

Есть код

```
 for j := 0 to mForm.ComponentCount - 1 do
    if mForm.Components[j] is TableFormInfo then
      //try
        //table := nil;
        //tempFmtable := nil;
        //tForm := nil;

        tForm := mForm.Components[j] as TableFormInfo;

        table := TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(tForm.Table));
        tempFmtable := TfmTableData.Create(MainWindow);
        tempFmtable.Name := tForm.Name;
        tempFmtable.tname := tForm.Table;
        //tempFmtable.Caption := Utf8ToAnsi(table.Description);
        tempFmtable.Left := tForm.LeftValue;
        tempFmtable.Top := tForm.TopValue;
        tempFmtable.Height := tForm.HeightValue;
        tempFmtable.Width := tForm.WidthValue;

        tempFmTable.IBQuery1.SQL.Clear;
        tempFmtable.IBQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from ' + table.Name);
        tempFmtable.IBQuery1.Open;
        tempFmtable.DragKind:=dkDock;
        tempFmtable.DragMode:=dmAutomatic;

        i := 0;
        querystr:='select ';
        while i <= tForm.ComponentCount - 1 do
          begin
          if tForm.Components[i] is TableFieldInfo then
          begin
            //querystr:='select ';
            //field := nil;
            //tempFmtable.Show;
            field := tForm.Components[i] as TableFieldInfo;
            tempFmtable.Caption:=tForm.Caption;
            tempFmtable.DBGrid1.Columns[i].FieldName := field.FieldNameValue;
            tempFmtable.DBGrid1.Columns[i].Title.Caption := field.DescriptionValue;
            tempFmtable.DBGrid1.Columns[i].Index := field.IndexValue;
            tempFmtable.DBGrid1.Columns[i].Visible := field.VisibleValue;
            tempFmtable.DBGrid1.Columns[i].Width:=field.WidthValue;
            //tempFmtable.CheckListBox1.Items.Add(field.Description);
            //tempFmtable.CheckListBox1.Checked[i] := field.Visible;
            //tempFmtable.Show;
             if field.VisibleValue  then querystr:=querystr+ConvertNameField(field.FieldNameValue)+', ';
          end;
            //inc(i);
          if tForm.Components[i] is SettingsFormInfo then
            begin
              //sForm:=nil;
              sForm:=tForm.Components[i] as SettingsFormInfo;
              tempsettings := TfmSettings.Create(tempFmtable);
              tempsettings.Caption:=sForm.Caption;
              //tempsettings := TfmSettings.Create(tempFmtable);
              tempsettings.Name := sForm.Name;
              tempsettings.Left := sForm.LeftValue;
              tempsettings.Top := sForm.TopValue;
              tempsettings.Height := sForm.HeightValue;
              tempsettings.Width := sForm.WidthValue;
              tempSettings.CheckListBox1.Clear;
              //for k:=0 to sForm.ComponentCount-1 do
              k:=0;
              while k<=sForm.ComponentCount-1 do
                begin
                  if sForm.Components[k] is ItemCheckListBoxInfo then
                    begin
                      //item:=nil;
                      item:=sForm.Components[k] as ItemCheckListBoxInfo;
                      tempsettings.CheckListBox1.Items.Add(item.TextValue);
                      tempsettings.CheckListBox1.Checked[item.IndexValue]:=item.CheckedValue
                    end;
                  if sForm.Components[k] is LabelInfo then
                    begin
                      //labelobj:=nil;
                      labelobj:=sForm.Components[k] as LabelInfo;
                      tempsettings.Label1.Caption:=labelobj.CaptionValue;
                    end;
                  if sForm.Components[k] is EditInfo then
                    begin
                      //edit:=nil;
                      edit:=sForm.Components[k] as EditInfo;
                      TEdit(tempsettings.FindComponent(edit.Name)).Text:=edit.TextValue;
                    end;
                    inc(k);
                end;
             if ((tForm.Components[i] is SettingsFormInfo) and (i=tForm.ComponentCount-1) and (k=sForm.ComponentCount)) then tempsettings.Show;
            end;
             //inc(i);
             //if ((tForm.Components[i] is SettingsFormInfo) and (i=tForm.ComponentCount-1) and (k=sForm.ComponentCount)) then tempsettings.Show;
             inc(i);
          end;

        {for i := 0 to table.Fields.ComponentCount - 1 do
        begin
          descr := Utf8ToAnsi(((table.Fields.Components[i]) as TFieldSpec).Description);
          tempFmtable.CheckListBox1.Items.Add(descr);
          tempFmtable.DBGrid1.Columns[i].Title.Caption := descr;
          tempFmtable.CheckListBox1.Checked[i] := true;
        end; }

        Delete(querystr, Length(querystr)-1, 1);
        querystr:=querystr+'from '+table.Name;
        tempFmTable.IBQuery1.SQL.Clear;
        tempFmtable.IBQuery1.SQL.Add(querystr);
        tempFmtable.IBQuery1.Open;
        for s := 0 to tForm.ComponentCount-1 do
          begin
            if tForm.Components[s] is TableFieldInfo then
              begin
                //field := nil;
                //tempFmtable.Show;
                field := tForm.Components[s] as TableFieldInfo;
                if field.VisibleValue then
                   begin
                     for t := 0 to tempFmtable.DBGrid1.Columns.Count-1 do
                       begin
                       if ((tempFmTable.DBGrid1.Columns[t].Title.Caption=field.DescriptionValue) and (tempFmtable.DBGrid1.Columns[t].FieldName=field.FieldNameValue)) then
                           tempFmTable.DBGrid1.Columns[t].Width:=field.WidthValue;
                       end;
                   end;
              end;
          end;
        tempFmtable.Show;
```

восстанавливающий форму с помощью десериализации. Хочу отметить, что перед использованием переменной `tForm` в строке

```
table := TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(tForm.Table));
```

она инициализируется в предыдущей строке

```
tForm := mForm.Components[j] as TableFormInfo;
```

Но несмотря на это при сборке возникает предупреждение

```
[dcc32 Warning] SerAndDeser.pas(298): W1036 Variable 'tForm' might not have been initialized
```

Почему? Как избавиться от этого предупреждения, не потеряв функциональности приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tForm := mForm.Components[0] as TableFormInfo;

Где не будь в начале инициализируй, да и пытайся сам разобраться, типичные же предупреждения.

Comment: а возникает потому что есть вариант что цикл не пройдет, теоретически

Comment: @savro я знаю точно из процесса создания приложения, что компоненты типа `TableFormInfo` точно есть в контейнере mForm. Но в таком случае раз нужна проверка на `is`, то от предупреждения невозможно избавиться?

Comment: То что ты знаешь компилятор не знает по этому и предупреждает.

Comment: @savro так от этого предупреждения избавиться нельзя?

Comment: я же написал решение, напиши в начале кода.
на функционал не повлияет, а вот компилятор успокоит

Comment: @savro все нашел решение проблемы - перед циклом надо было

    tForm:=nil;

Comment: очень даже вариант